# Must every function in the subclass be defined in the superclass?

Tags: java, oop

```
class shape {
    private String name;
    public shape(){
        System.out.println("in shape, default");
    }
    public shape(String n){
        System.out.println("in shape, one parameter");
        name=n;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
};

class square extends shape {
    private int length;
    public square(){
        super("square");
    }
    public void f(){
        System.out.println("in f, square!");
    }
};    

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        shape newObject=new square();
        System.out.println(newObject.getName());
        newObject.f();
    }
};
```

When I try to call the function `f()` in the main method it throws an error, but when I define `f()` in the superclass `shape`, it works. `Shape` is not an abstract class.

Can anyone explain to me why this is?

Thank you!

Comment: FYI, the trailing semicolon after the class is not required in java

Comment: You should respect Java naming convention to make your code easier to read for all. For instance name your classes using upper-case at start (`shape` should be `Shape`). It is common way to not confuse types with members of classes (for instance it helps to see that `Shape.someMethod()` can only be invocation of static method rather than `shape.someMethod()` which looks more like invocation of non-static method on instance of `Shape` class)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the *compile-time* type of your `newObject` variable is `shape`. That means the only members that the compiler knows about are the ones in `shape`, and that doesn't include `f()`.

If you want to use members which are specific to a given class, you need to use a variable of that type, e.g.

```
square newObject = new square();
newObject.f(); // This is fine
```

As asides:

- You should follow Java naming conventions (`Shape` and `Square` instead of `shape` and `square`)
- You don't need semi-colons after class declarations
- You should outdent the first line of each class declaration... it looks very odd at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Shape Class does not have function "f". You can use below `square newObject=new square();`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Jon said

If you know `newObject` will be of type `Square`, you can do this:

```
Shape newObject = new Square();
((Square)newObject).f();
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are creating an instance of `square`, you are assigning it to `shape`, which is the superclass. And it does not have the function defined, and hence the compilation error.

Instead of  `shape newObject=new square();`
use: `square newObject=new square();`

Answer (score 0):

You can only call methods defined in the class the object is declared as, not the methods of class it is instance of.
So in this case:

```
shape newObject=new square();
newObject.f();
```

You can't call f(), but in if You write it like this:

```
square newObject=new square();
newObject.f();
```

You can (because now it is declared as square).

If You want to call method of the subclass you can cast the object on it (providing it really is an instance of it, in other case You'll get an exception here):

```
shape newObject=new square();
((square)newObject).f();
```

Also as mentioned before, name You classes beginning with an uppercase letter (Shape, Square). ;)